# Azure Pipeline - Self Hosted Agent YAML how to copy release files to my Azure VM

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure Pipeline using a Pool of a Self Hosted Agent and I have the following YAML that is working great:

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master
# Al usuar el pool default, usara de la organizacion el pool que cree como Self hosted CustomAgentSelfInsurance
pool: 
  name: Default
  #vmImage: 'windows-latest'

#container: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

variables:
- group: 'CertPass'
  #solution: '**/SelfInsurance.sln'
  #buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  #buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  #pathToMageTool: "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.8 Tools\\mage.exe\""

steps:

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download Pfx
  name: myCertificatePfx
  inputs:
    secureFile: ventasmlcert.pfx
    
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download sni
  name: snInstallPfx
  inputs:
    secureFile: SnInstallPfx.exe    
    
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download Testpipelineapp
  name: testPipelineapp
  inputs:
    secureFile: TestPipelineapp.zip    
    
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestPipelineapp.zip'
    cleanDestinationFolder: false
    overwriteExistingFiles: true    

#- task: PowerShell@2
#  env:
#    SN_INSTALL_PFX: $(snInstallPfx.secureFilePath)
#    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX: $(myCertificatePfx.secureFilePath)
#    MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD: $(certpass)
#  inputs:
#    targetType: 'inline'
#    script: '&"$($ENV:SN_INSTALL_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX)" "$($ENV:MYCERTIFICATE_PFX_PASSWORD)"'
    
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build .csproj file'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=false /p:OutDir="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\publish_output"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

        
# Command line
# Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: TestPipelineapp.exe   #'echo Write your commands here.' 
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
```

What I need is to create a task that takes my build release files and copy them to a folder in my Azure VM.

Any clue and example on how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Environment` to configure your VM for azure devops to have access, and use the deployment environment to run a download task -> copy to your folder.

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops